# how to write modular angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

Please feel free to rephrase the title as necessary.

I do know how to write controllers the modular way.

```
var controllers = {};
controllers.ToDoController = function($scope){
   //...
};
```

But you can do the same as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ToDoController', '$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
   //...
});
```

Above you are defining the arguments for the controller method. How do we do this in the first approach?

Comment: I think you are looking for this - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-thinking-differently-about-organization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved using dependency injection:

```
var controllers = {};
controllers.ToDoController = function($scope, $location) {
   //...
};

controllers.ToDoController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
```

You can also check the official docs and examples [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)